# How to search by table column that has spaces in the name?

Tags: c#, atata

I am building a test that is supposed to search through a table and find an object based on the column name. The problem is, the column name has a space in it, for example: "Friendly name"

I am simply wondering how to get the atata framework to find this. Custom search parameters like  `[Term("Friendly name")]` are not working in table objects.

I've also tried to use `[Term(TermCase.Sentence)]`, and it does compile but doesn't work with tables either. I am not super familiar with atata yet to know how to get this to work properly. The compiler is "Unable to locate visible column".

Here is the test code line:

```
pageObject.Table.Rows.Count.Get(out count).
    Table.Rows[x => x.Friendly name == "OBJECTNAME"].Click().
```

Any advice would be greatly helpful.

```
<thead class="MuiTableHead-root-325">
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root-326 MuiTableRow-head-329">
<th class="MuiTableCell-root-331 MuiTableCell-head-332" scope="col">Column name</th>
<th class="MuiTableCell-root-331 MuiTableCell-head-332" scope="col">Column name2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root-326">
<td class="MuiTableCell-root-331 MuiTableCell-body-333">TESTCELL</td>
<td class="MuiTableCell-root-331 MuiTableCell-body-333">TESTCELL2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Xpath example: `div[@id="root"]/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[1]`

As you can see, there isn't much in the elements I can work with. These tables are generated dynamically so the information may be moved or deleted, but for the testing purposes, this isn't much of an issue.

```
{
    using _ = Example;

    public class Example : Page<_>
    {
        public Table<ExampleTableRow, _> Table { get; private set; }

        public class ExampleTableRow : TableRow<_>
        {
            [Term(TermCase.Sentence)]
            public Text<_> ColumnName { get; private set; }
            public Clickable<_> Edit { get; private set; }
        } 
        [FindByXPath("div[@id='root']/div[2]/path/input")]
        public TextInput<_> RenameTest { get; private set; }
    }
}

and the class..

int count;
            Go.To<ExampleTable>().
            Table.Rows.Count.Get(out count).
            Table.Rows[x => x.ColumnName == "Friendly name"].Edit.Click().
            RenameTest.Set("Reanametest").
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[Term("Friendly name")]` and `[Term(TermCase.Sentence)]` are equivalent if the property is named `FriendlyName`. I would try to use `[Term(TermMatch.Contains, TermCase.Sentence)]`. If it will work, it means that there are extra characters in the beginning or at the end of the column header (`th`).

Anyway, it will be very helpful to resolve your issue if you share the part of your table's HTML code and page object code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yevgeniy! I edited the main post a bit. But I am not sure where i will find the page object code?

Comment: The page object code is where this table property and table row class are defined in your page class.

Comment: Have you tried to use `[FindByColumnIndex(0)]` (0 can be replaced with specific column index) instead of `[Term(TermCase.Sentence)]`?

Comment: Also ensure that your `Table` property is bound to the correct `<table>` element.

Comment: Findbycolumnindex seemed to do the trick. I was able to find ways using other columns like an id column which is static.